# Como hacer que un rs.updateInt sea nulo

Tags: java, jdbc, nullpointerexception

Es mi primera pregunta en este foro asi que espero poder formularla correctamente.
Estoy intentando cambiar un valor int a nulo en una base de datos mediante JDBC, el caso es que al tratarse de un entero, este no puede ser nulo y la primera ayuda que me dan es que ponga un cast de Integer, pero aun así al ejecutar me salta un NullPointerException y no se de que manera puedo cambiarlo sin que salte esta excepción. Aqui teneis el código.

```
public void grabar(Usuario u) throws BusinessException {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
        stmt = ConexionJdbc.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        if (rs.next()) {
            rs.moveToInsertRow();
            rs.updateString(2, u.getNombre());
            rs.updateString(3, u.getPassword());
            rs.updateInt(4, u.getTipo());
            if (u.getTipo() == 1) {
                try {                       
                    rs.updateString(6, null);
                    rs.updateInt(7, u.getDepartamento());
                } catch (SQLException s) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DAOGrupo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error de Query", s);
                    throw new BusinessException("El grupo debe ser null");
                }
            } else if (u.getTipo() == 2) {
                try {
                    rs.updateString(6, u.getGrupo());                       
                    rs.updateInt(7, (Integer) null);
                } catch (SQLException s) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DAOGrupo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error de Query", s);
                    throw new BusinessException("El departamento debe ser null");
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    rs.updateString(6, null);
                    rs.updateInt(7, Integer.parseInt(null));
                } catch (SQLException s) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DAOGrupo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error de Query", s);
                    throw new BusinessException("El grupo y el departamento deben ser null");
                }
            }
            rs.updateInt(5, u.getRol());                
            rs.insertRow();
        }

    } catch (SQLException s) {
        Logger.getLogger(DAODepartamento.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error de Query", s);
        throw new BusinessException("Error en operación con la BD.");
    } finally {
        ConexionJdbc.cerrar(rs);
        ConexionJdbc.cerrar(stmt);
    }
```

Comment: ¿A qué dato te refieres específicamente y por qué debes convertirlo a `null`? Sería bueno que digas lo que quieres hacer, no sea que estés adoptando una solución equivocada para resolver el problema.

Comment: A la linea donde pongo " rs.updateInt(7, (Integer) null);"
Se trata de insertar un usuario y dependiendo del tipo que séa(1,2,3), grupo o departamento deben ser nulos o ambos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas convertir un entero a nulo para hacer lo que quieres, aquí en esta línea:

```
                rs.updateInt(7, (Integer) null);
```

`ResultSet` tiene un método [`updateNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateNull(int)) para esos casos, sólo tendrías que hacer esto:

```
                rs.updateNull(7);
```

Aquí no se pasa ningún valor, sólo el índice de la columna, que sería `7` en este caso.

Comment: Este era una de las opciones que puse pero me saltaba otro error que me acabo de dar cuenta de cual es, ya que al ser una clave ajena no puede actualizarse a null y si no me equivoco debo de hacer una consulta donde esté su clave primaria y ahi hacer el rs.updateNull(x);

Comment: @Nathan si la columna a la que quieres asignar el valor `NULL` no admite nulos, ese es un problema de la lógica de tu programa, la cual debes revisar a fondo para no cometer errores lamentables. Yo veo demasiadas idas y venidas en tu código, y me da la impresión de que debes refinar tu lógica, analizando a fondo qué es lo que quieres lograr. No puedes dejar un código al azar, que asigne datos que a veces pueden admitir nulos y a veces no. Eso denota un error de lógica que debe corregirse a otro nivel.

Comment: Para eso tengo los ifs, para que no sea al azar, si no  mas bien dependiendo de qué es lo que quiero hacer con el programa a la hora de insertar un valor u otro. Ademas que estoy empezando a programar, llevo menos de un año, así que es lógico que no pueda refinarlo tanto como los que llevan en este mundo muchos mas años. Nadie empieza sabiendo. Igualmente gracias por tu observación.

Comment: @Nathan mi observación ha sido hecha con la finalidad de ayudar a revisar el código. En el primer comentario dijiste que intentaste usar `rs.updateNull` y que en algún caso te dio error al no admitir nulos en esa columna. Si eso ocurrió es porque tienes un error de lógica en tu código sí o sí y debes corregirlo. Es a eso a lo que me refiero. Con las observaciones de otros se puede aprender y se pueden ver errores que no se ven a simple vista. Todo es cuestión de paciencia.

Comment: Lo has entendido mal, he dicho "otro error" que el cual es este: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inventario`.`usuario`, CONSTRAINT `fk_grupos_usuario` FOREIGN KEY (`grupo`) REFERENCES `grupo` (`idgrupo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
De ahí a que saque la lógica que he dicho en un primer momento.

Comment: @Nathan es igual, es un error de lógica. Has diseñado los datos de una manera y ahora en el código se viola una de las restricciones que estableciste al diseñar las tablas en la base de datos. Por ejemplo, si estableces `NULL` a una columna que tiene datos relacionados en otra tabla, aquellos datos quedarían huérfanos y por eso saltaría la restricción. Precisamente a eso me refería cuando te decía que ***«Eso denota un error de lógica que debe corregirse a otro nivel. »***

Comment: "si estableces NULL a una columna que tiene datos relacionados en otra tabla, aquellos datos quedarían huérfanos y por eso saltaría la restricción." Esque si esa columna la hago NULL, es por que no tiene que relacionarse con su predecesor, el ejercicio pide eso, que dependiendo de un tipo de usuario, éste podra o no tener relacion con la columna que le corresponda.

Comment: Puedo ponerte el enunciado si quieres por que creo que no me estoy expresando con claridad.

Comment: @Nathan el error que indicaste antes: `*Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (inventario.usuario, CONSTRAINT fk_grupos_usuario FOREIGN KEY (grupo) REFERENCES grupo (idgrupo) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`* es claro. Se está violando una restricción en la base de datos, sea donde sea. Por tanto debes revisar la lógica para que eso no ocurra, o debes revisar la forma en que diseñaste las tablas para quitar esa restricción si fuera preciso. De todos modos, una cosa y otra escapan ya al alcance de esta pregunta. Inicialmente tú querías setear un valor `NULL`.

Comment: Las tablas no estan diseñadas por mi, si no por el profesor, asi que va a ser mi lógica. Pero ya te digo esto es lo que me pide exactamente:A la hora de añadir y modificar usuarios habrá que asegurar que se cumplen las siguientes restricciones que no están implementadas a nivel de base de datos: Los usuarios de tipo profesor tienen que estar relacionados con un departamento y no estar relacionados con ningún grupo. Es decir, que si el tipousuario es profesor, el campo departamento debe ser distinto de null, mientras que el campo grupo será necesariamente null.

Comment: A la hora de añadir y modificar usuarios habrá que asegurar que se cumplen las siguientes restricciones que no están implementadas a nivel de base de datos: Esto no se si tiene algo que ver con lo que estas intentando explicarme

Comment: @Nathan entiendo. Pero esto tiene que ser abordado en otra pregunta distinta. Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas. La duda inicial era poder pasar un valor nulo a un `ResultSet`. Eso se hace con `updateNull`. Resuelto eso, si aparece otro problema, conviene que lo expliques en una nueva pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Deacuerdo, gracias de todas formas por tu tiempo.

Comment: @Nathan de nada. Si crees que la respuesta dada responde a la duda planteada inicialmente la puedes marcar como resuelta. Si en un futuro alguien tiene un problema parecido esta pregunta podría servirle para resolver ese problema concreto. Y ante cualquier otra duda, aquí hay varios usuarios con experiencia sobre Java que podrán ayudarte con gusto. Saludos.